# How to differentiate a D-pad movement from a Joystick movement?

Tags: android, android-tv, gamepad

I need to have two different behaviors, one for D-pad and another for the analog Joystick (on the same gamepad).

The problem is that on the `onGenericMotionEvent` callback, both have the same information on the `MotionEvent` and I am not able to distinguish them.

```
// d-pad
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=-1.5259255E-5, y[0]=-1.5259255E-5, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=151637936, downTime=0, deviceId=5, source=0x1000010 }

// analog joystick
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=0.64507514, y[0]=0.710811, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=151650802, downTime=0, deviceId=5, source=0x1000010 }
```

Is it possible to identify which kind of input is being used? How?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I have the same problem but it seems there is no way to distinguish between these two input methods. Would be really annoying...

Comment: Seems like DS4 controllers do not claim DPAD source when you use the DPAD.  You get a Joystick source event with the Hat values set to min/max depending on what you pressed.  To support DS4 anyway it looks like you need to query X and XHat, see which is larger (abs) and use that.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue, and I had to dig through [this helpful Git user's project](https://github.com/nathanRamaNoodles/Tinker-Controller) to figure out how he did it. The way you differentiate between the different joysticks (and the D-pad) is to use each direction's specific **axis**.

If you read the [Android documentation's page](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input) very carefully (I didn't pick up on it), it does show how you can differentiate between the various joysticks and their directions:

[image: Android documentation for different axis/labels]

This image shows that the left joystick uses axes **AXIS_X** and **AXIS_Y**, whereas the right joystick uses **AXIS_Z** and and **AXIS_RZ**. For the D-pad, I used **AXIS_HAT_X** and **AXIS_HAT_Y**. The following snippet from my code (in Kotlin) shows how you can access each of these individually:

Note: I also had my seek bars set to a range of 0-100, which is why I have the conversion math at the bottom of `processJoystickInput()`.

```
private fun processJoystickInput(event: MotionEvent, historyPos: Int) {

    val inputDevice = event.device

    val newJoystickValues = floatArrayOf(
            getCenteredAxis(event, inputDevice, MotionEvent.AXIS_X, historyPos),
            getCenteredAxis(event, inputDevice, MotionEvent.AXIS_Y, historyPos),
            getCenteredAxis(event, inputDevice, MotionEvent.AXIS_Z, historyPos),
            getCenteredAxis(event, inputDevice, MotionEvent.AXIS_RZ, historyPos),
            getCenteredAxis(event, inputDevice, MotionEvent.AXIS_HAT_X, historyPos),
            getCenteredAxis(event, inputDevice, MotionEvent.AXIS_HAT_Y, historyPos))

    // Update based on the new x and y values
    val throttleSeekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.throttle_seekBar)
    val yawSeekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.yaw_seekBar)
    val pitchSeekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.pitch_seekBar)
    val rollSeekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.roll_seekBar)
    val dpadXSeekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.dpadX_seekBar)
    val dpadYSeekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.dpadY_seekBar)

    // Convert the float range (-1.00 to 1.00) to Int (0 to 100)
    yawSeekBar.progress = ((newJoystickValues[0] + 1) * 50).toInt()
    throttleSeekBar.progress = ((newJoystickValues[1] + 1) * 50).toInt()
    rollSeekBar.progress = ((newJoystickValues[2] + 1) * 50).toInt()
    pitchSeekBar.progress = ((newJoystickValues[3] + 1) * 50).toInt()
    dpadXSeekBar.progress = ((newJoystickValues[4] + 1) * 50).toInt()
    dpadYSeekBar.progress = ((newJoystickValues[5] + 1) * 50).toInt()
}

override fun onGenericMotionEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    // Check that the event came from a game controller

    return if (event.source and(InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK) == InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK
            && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        // Process the movements starting from the
        // earliest historical position in the batch
        (0 until event.historySize).forEach { i ->
            // Process the event at historical position i
            processJoystickInput(event, i)
        }

        // Process the current movement sample in the batch (position -1)
        processJoystickInput(event, -1)
        true
    } else {
        super.onGenericMotionEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your provided information, they look like from the same source, which is Joystick (0x1000010). You can check these information on [Input Device](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html) object.

The following information were from [Handling Controller Actions](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html#input):

> To verify that a connected input device is a game controller, call `getSources()` to obtain a combined bit field of input source types supported on that device.
>
> A source type of `SOURCE_GAMEPAD` indicates that the input device has gamepad buttons (for example, `BUTTON_A`). Note that this source type does not strictly indicate if the game controller has D-pad buttons, although most gamepads typically have directional controls.
>
> A source type of `SOURCE_DPAD` indicates that the input device has D-pad buttons (for example, `DPAD_UP`).
>
> A source type of `SOURCE_JOYSTICK` indicates that the input device has analog control sticks (for example, a joystick that records movements along `AXIS_X` and `AXIS_Y`).

You may also want to check [Supporting Multiple Controller Input](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/game-controllers/multiple-controllers.html#detect).

Comment: I need to distinguish the two different inputs (dpad and analog) from the same joystick source, not two different sources

Answer (score 0):

From the Android docs (https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input):

> Android reports D-pad UP and DOWN presses as AXIS_HAT_Y events with a
>   range from -1.0 (up) to 1.0 (down), and D-pad LEFT or RIGHT presses as
>   AXIS_HAT_X events with a range from -1.0 (left) to 1.0 (right).
>
> Some controllers instead report D-pad presses with a key code. If your game cares about D-pad presses, you should treat the hat axis
>   events and the D-pad key codes as the same input events, as
>   recommended in table 2.

The two controllers I've worked with (NVIDIA SHIELD BlueTooth and Microsoft XBOX360 wired) both generate AXIS_HAT_* movement events.

Comment: DS4 as well.  DPad is always a MotionEvent, source=Joystick, DPad has to be read from XHat/YHat values.